# What is the Haar measure on the unit sphere?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, algebraic-topology, haar-measure

I try to understand the proof of Lemma 4.2. in the paper 'The Euler equations as a differential inclusion' by De Lellis and Székelyhidi. In the proof they use the Haar measure on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. How is the Haar measure defined here?

Comment: My guess would be treating it as a homogeneous space of the special orthogonal group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#Measures_on_homogeneous_spaces

Comment: Thank you for the hint! If I understood it correctly, this means that $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} f(Av) \: dv = \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} f(v) \: dv$ holds for all $A\in SO(n)$ and all integrable functions on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. In the paper they then conclude $ \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}(v,v\otimes v - \frac{I_{n}}{n}) \: dv = 0$. Does this mean that there exists an $A\in SO(n)$ such that $(Av,Av\otimes Av - \frac{I_{n}}{n}) = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

See Section 2.1 in these [lecture notes](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eavner/teaching/S6-2414/LN5.pdf) and especially Remark 2.6. One can construct the Haar measure as the normalized area of a subset of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

To randomly choose a point from a distribution that is uniform on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ according to the Haar measure, it suffices to take $n$ normally-distributed random variables $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ and choose the point to correspond to the normalized vector $$\frac{(X_1,\cdots,X_n)}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}}$$